# cURL parecer 100% identica a minha requisição usando navegador comum

Tags: php, libcurl

Preciso de realizar algumas funções padrão que realizo sempre manualmente,e gostaria de automatizar isso. Testei com *iframe*, mas sem sucesso, não da para ler os nós do documento.

Ai pensei em usar  a biblioteca *cURL*, assim obtenho o conteúdo da página *( poderia ser **file_get_contents()** )*, mas percebi que ambas as opções voltam para página de login do site *(inclusive logado, pedindo apenas para prosseguir)*, mas se eu acesso a mesma página no meu navegador, ele não é redirecionado para tela de LOGIN.

Ai que vem a pergunta, o que fazer para que a requisição do *cURL* seja 100% idêntica a que eu faço no meu navegador comum, ou seja, se fosse assim, eu iria para página que eu apontei, ao invés de voltar ao login.

**Obs:** no cURL eu configurei o `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` para um arquivo `.txt` onde possui os cookies *( no qual me asseguro de estar logado )* razão pela qual o *cURL* volta para página de login *( já logado, apenas pedindo permissão para prosseguir )*.

Acredito que o site de certa forma detecta isso, seria alguma constante que deixei de definir no *cURL*?

Aqui está como configuro o cURL atualmente:

```
$url = "http://trade.aliexpress.com/order_detail.htm?orderId=71064520859834";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);

curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Você só vai conseguir ficar logado conforme as regras da página que exigem a autenticação, não basta jogar cookies lá, existem situações aonde o id do cookie (sendo um cookie de sessão) expira de tempos em tempos, ao ler sua pergunta me da a entender que você quer fazer um webproxy é isso? Você pode postar a url que esta tentando se manter autenticado?

Comment: Não entendo ao certo o que é um webproxy, mas você diz que sessão expira de tempos em tempos, mas se eu fizer o login agora, copiar os cookies e atualizar meu arquivo de cookies(defino na constante COOKIEFILE), não entendo onde "expirar" acontece.  Obg pelo comentário! @GuilhermeNascimento - Autenticação persiste(pelo menos dá a entender), o problema de fato é a página que aparece anteriormente que pede para que eu continue(não exige senha) ao invés de apontar a que de fato eu defini, vou colocar a URL.

Comment: Por isto que pedi pra por o link (valor de `$url`), talvez assim cheguemos a raiz do problema, pois o problema pode ser uma série de fatores. WebProxy é semelhante aos proxys, mas o acesso é totalmente via web, ou seja um outra página carrega o conteudo de uma página desejada utilizando linguagens server-side.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, atualizei com o valor da URL. O que desejo apenas fazer ai, é ver se existe um tracking code e se existir, realizar alguma função(gravar no BD), e só. API do Aliexpress não conta com isso(procurei bastante, é mais virada para quem Vende e não quem Compra).

Comment: Eles não fornecem API? Se tiver é melhor do que ficar sofrendo com webcrawler.

Comment: @WilliamOkano , eu pensei que tinha uma API, e eu achei, mas API deles é mais concentrada para quem vende, na verdade, para quem compra eu não achei nada, por exemplo, obter código de rastreio de terminada order, e/ou descobrir quantas ordens na conta falta para pagar.. etc, essas coisas eu juro que procurei muito, e nada achei.

Answer (score 1):

Você está sempre sendo redirecionado para a tela de login pois você está criando um cookie jar porém ele está vazio. Você precisa popular os cookies do curl com os seus cookies atuais.

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $_SERVER["HTTP_COOKIE"]);`

Porém observe que mesmo assim pode ser que você ainda seja redirecionado para a página de login visto que podem existir outros mecanismos de autenticação no site.

Comment: cookie já estava populado, pois o COOKIE_FILE possuía um arquivo .txt onde copiei todos meus cookies e coloquei lá, mas obrigado pela dica, já não preciso ficar repassando os cookies do navegador para .txt.

Comment: De toda foram o HTTP_COOKIE só vai pegar os cookies do domínio atual.

Acho que o mais simples pra você seria criar um robozinho individual e criar uma API pra você ler dele.

Comment: Como assim robozinho? William, poderia me dar uma melhor ideia do que esta querendo dizer?

Comment: Por robê quero dizer uma aplicação automatizada que vai ficar rodando ad-eternum, ele vai ficar lendo seus pedidos (de acordo com determinadas regras) e populando um banco por exemplo. Esse banco você poderia acessar para ler as infos. Um webcrawler, igual você quer fazer, mas que fique rodando eterno e que seja "standalone" (fora da sua aplicação, seja uma aplicação individual)